# ListView Multichoice listener is not working properly when we enable from ImageView

Tags: android, listview, multichoiceitems

[image]

after releasing the long click, the item is getting deselected automatically.

```
holder.attach_img.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    if (lvChatList.isItemChecked(position))
                        lvChatList.setItemChecked(position, false);
                    else
                        lvChatList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: please post the xml file

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, the View hierarchy in Android is represented by a tree. When you return true from the onLongClick() - it means that the View that currently received the event is the true event receiver and the event should not be propagated to the other Views in the tree; when you return false - you let the event be passed to the other Views that may consume it. So for your current scenario, just make onLongClick(View view) returns return `true` instead of return `false` and check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        if (lvChatList.isItemChecked(position))
                    lvChatList.setItemChecked(position, false);
                else
                    lvChatList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
    }
```

Comment: yes after returning true also, same like after releasing the long click its happening

Comment: will you able to show your some more code, because i have implemented it on my sample app, if you want to i can show you my code.